'UserInput\01-starting-project\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command

'UserInput\01-starting-project\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1222
throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\UDEMY REACT LAST\vite\bin\vite.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1045:27)
at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:215:24)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.5.1
I am trying to run my Reactjs application
D:\01-starting-project> npm run dev

I am getting the error shown above.
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "forms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite buNPild",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.3.5"
  }
}


Have you run npm install first?

yes done   > npm install
